# Registering Event Attendees and Volunteers using different Profiles

Tags: civievent, online-registration

We need attendees and volunteers for an event. We have been creating two parallel CiviEvent events for this one real event.

We've been registering event attendees with one event, then setting up an additional event for the volunteers for that same actual event. For these two (simultaneous) events, the first event participant role defaults to Attendee, and the second event participant role defaults to volunteer.

It occurs to us that we could expose Participant Role in a profile so that the registrant can choose from two roles with a pulldown "Participant Role = Volunteer or Participant Role = Attendee"

The issue is then that we want to collect different information from attendees and volunteers. Is there some logical way to do this, beyond something like "If you chose Volunteer, please scroll to the bottom of the page and fill in your info  there."

Ideally, the choice of Volunteer for the first field would change all the other fields, or flip from one profile to another. Or am I looking at this the wrong way.

Thanks for any tips!
Rick

Answer (score 1):

One option is the [Profile Conditionals extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/profile-conditionals)  It's not the easiest thing to configure but works well when you get it right.

Comment: We'll install it and give it a go!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas come to mind, both would require Drupal to work.

You could create a [CiviCRM-integrated-Webform](https://civicrm.org/de/extensions/webform-civicrm-integration) and use conditionals there to adapt the form depending on the role of the participant.

There is also an extension called [RemoteEvents](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.remoteevent) that would allow you to do that. Pleas note that this would imply a rather complex new approach to set up event registration and will probably not be worth the effort if you only want two registration profiles - if you plan to do fancy event stuff in the future it may be worth a look though. Also it needs Drupal 9.

Comment: Thanks Fabian - this particular installation isn't Drupal but others of ours are D7. This site is WordPress 6.0 and CiviCRM 5.50.1